# Preventing Nokogiri from escaping characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have created a text node and inserted into my document like so:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcce081481c "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style'%>">]>
```

When I try to save the document with this:

```
File.open('ng.html', 'w+'){|f| f << page.to_html}
```

I get this in the actual document:

```
&lt;%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style'%&gt;
```

Is there a way to disable the escaping and save my page with my erb tags intact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are obliged to escape some characters in text elements like:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

If you want your text verbatim use a CDATA section since everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.

Nokogiri example:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |b|
  b.html do
    b.head do
      b.cdata "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style'%>"
   end
  end
end
builder.to_html
```

This should keep you erb tags intact!

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you want to use the ["<<" method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-i-%3C%3C) to insert raw XML like this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |b|
  b.html do
    b.head do
      b << stylesheet_link_tag 'style'
    end
  end
end
builder.to_xml
```