# Using PowerShell to parse XML and edit data into Excel, strange foreign characters appearing

Tags: xml, excel, powershell

I'm having an issue when I use PowerShell to copy data from an XML sheet into an Excel sheet. The data from the XML file looks like this: `<TrackTitle>I'm the One</TrackTitle>`, but the result in Excel looks like this: `IÂ’'m the One`. Anyone know what might be happening with the apostrophe? All I'm doing is grabbing that TrackTitle node and inserting it into an Excel spreadsheet, nothing fancy. I think it's an encoding issue? But I don't know how to affect the encoding of the information as I move it. Thanks a bunch for any help.

Edit: Here's the hex code of the passage in question. In the HxD hex editor, the funky characters show up as well.

In the XML document in HxD,

```
"IÂ’'m the One" =  "49 C2 92 27 6D 20 74 68 65 20 4F 6E 65"
```

If I use *Edit → Copy as → Editor view*, this comes up when I select `IÂ’'m the One`:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00004AA0                    49 C2 92 27 6D 20 74 68 65 20        IÂ’'m the 
00004AB0  4F 6E 65                                         One
```

It's strange that the characters get distorted even in HxD. In the XML it looks completely normal.

Comment: Sure looks like an encoding issue. Try opening the file in some hex editor to see the actual bytes in the file.

Comment: Can you break that down a bit more? I forgot to mention I'm pretty new to this, I've been teaching myself for a month or so. Is there possibly a simple online hex editor I could use, just to examine the problem? Or will I need to download something? And assuming it is some kind of encoding problem, where can I go from there? Thanks for responding!

Comment: [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a decent hex editor for Windows. The author provides both an installable and a portable version (scroll down the download page for the latter). Open the file in HxD and find the passage that's giving you trouble. Edit your question and copy/paste both hex and text view (*Edit > Copy as > Editor view*) of that passage as well as the first line of the file into your question.

Comment: Thank you! Before I do that, I noticed that if I call the xml element right in the PowerShell console, the funky characters appear. So it's not a problem of moving from XML to PowerShell to Excel, it's a problem in Powershell itself it seems. Going to edit the question now with the hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two bytes `C2 92` right before the single quote (`27`) are a non-printable control character ([U+0092](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0092)). Not sure what the purpose of this Unicode character is, or how the character got into your XML data (if I had to guess I'd say it was copy/pasted from somewhere, perhaps some [HTML text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590056/1630171)).

If you open the file in Notepad and position the cursor right of the single quote in `I'` you most likely need to press <kbd>←</kbd> 3 times to move the cursor from the right side of the `'` to the left side of the `I`.

Simply remove the character from the XML file (delete the faulty character sequence, type `I'` in its place, then save the file) and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hmmm well this has been happening with other XML sheets I'm accessing as well. Is there a way to correct this in Powershell automatically?

Comment: I just checked a different XML sheet and tried the same thing - it seems to happen any time there is an uncommon character. It replaces the character with a bunch of seemingly unrelated strange characters. This "É" turned into "Ã‰". Any idea how to correct this without changing every XML sheet? I found [this](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) which definitely accounts for my problem, but I don't know anything about encoding to fix it in Powershell.

Comment: You should be able to remove the spurious control character with something like `-creplace "I.{1,2}'m", "I'm"`. There's no magic spell for fixing arbitrary character/encoding issues, though. If it's just an encoding problem you might be able to fix it by specifying the correct enconding when reading the file (e.g. `-Encoding UTF8`).

Comment: Ohhhh wow yeah that fixed it. I'm self-teaching so there are plenty of noob problems for me to overcome. Thank you so much for that advice. This website is really amazing.